# Unsure Of Where To Load Scrapy On the Anaconda Platform

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am exceedingly naive when it comes to the topic of scraping websites. Up to this point, I have manually scraped or had to grab data from pre-generated datasets. There is an analytic problem I want to tackle though, a problem that due to its scale requires scraping. So I have decided to try and learn how to scrape in python. Scrapy was the tool I was recommended to use, so that is what I'll be utilizing.

I am trying to follow the tutorial for loading up my first Scrapy project, but have hit a snag. When I try to input the code to start a project in Spyder to start a new project:

```
import scrapy
$scrapy startproject ProjectName
```

I get the following error in the console:

```
import scrapy

scrapy startproject ProjectName
  File "<ipython-input-2-7c662bff7403>", line 1
    scrapy startproject ProjectName
      ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there another editor or environment I am supposed to be running Scrapy in? I have tried booting up Scrapy using the ScrapyShell command in the terminal, but that seems like an inefficient approach, seeing as I have no clue how I would save any scripts I generate when running code in the terminal. Is there some custom editor for Scrapy I'm not aware of?

Comment: The `scrapy startproject ProjectName` command is meant to be executed on a system terminal, like the one where you would run `conda install`, not a Python interpreter. It generates files that you can then edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Scrapy is properly installed, you should go to the project directory in the terminal window.

For example:

(venv) C:\Users\Laptop\PycharmProjects>scrapy startproject ProjectName